# Creating FCM Topics takes a long time to show in console

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

When I subscribe to a topic which doesn't exist.. why would it take a day long to apear in the Firebase Console ? would be created directly or after 1 day ? (Can I access it even when it's not shown in the console ? )

I have an application that uses push notifications so I will create a topic for every user in case he has more that one device or token was deleted. is there a good way to achieve this rather than topics ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic is immediately created when a device subscribes to it, or a server app send data to it. But it indeed takes a few hours before tokens show up in the dropdown in the Firebase Notifications console.