# Topic Won't Save in Firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to let a user subscribe to a Topic and save it in Firebase. I've followed the guides from firebase.google.com and have added the following code when a user taps a button:

```
[[FIRMessaging messaging] subscribeToTopic:@"/topics/sampletopic"];
```

Nothing happens though when I test clicking this button. I've added what is necessary to the podfile. What am I missing?

edit: where does this even show up in Firebase? Where can I see my saved topics?

Comment: Topics are created on demand when a user subscribes to them or when a message is pushed to them. It may take a few hours before the topic shows up in the Firebase Console. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181963/creating-fcm-topics-takes-a-long-time-to-show-in-console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A topic is created automatically so long that there is a subscriber. However, for FCM, it takes about 24 hours for it to be available in the console, as also mentioned in the following posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39371301/4625829
- [How To Create Topic in FCM Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37367292/4625829)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37848400/4625829

You can view it when you are going to **Send a New Message** in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com), then in the *Target* section, choose ***Topic***.