# Create topics from App engine and send message

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application server hosted on app engine that serves as a mobile backend for a Yammer/Facebook/Chatter like app. I need to be able to send notification messages from this app engine JAVA server to Firebase connection server.

I have gone through the example to create topic manually from console and send the notification to the mobile client. I was able to get that working.

However, what I cannot find on your documentation is a step by step example / process to send notification messages to a topic from a Java server. I looked [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/serverreference/packages).

Can you please point me in the right direction? I need to:

1. Create topic from App Engine server.
2. Send messages (either XMPP / HTTP) to that topic from App Engine server.

Also, since we are using the same google project ID for both Firebase and App Engine, does Firebase support seamless authentication (without having to create a credential)?

Thanks.

Comment: [Topics are automatically created when you send a message to them or when a device subscribes to them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181963/creating-fcm-topics-takes-a-long-time-to-show-in-console/39183389#39183389). Sending messages from Java does not require an SDK. It's a simple matter of executing a HTTP POST. See [these results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-cloud-messaging%5D+%5Bjava%5D+HTTP+POST).

Comment: Thanks Frank ! I tried posting by setting the notification message in the format specified by the documentation and POSTed to the url https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send. In spite of setting the right format and the right SERVER KEY found under project settings -> Notifications, I keep getting a 401 !   Any help here would be really appreciated.

Comment: If you're having problems getting code to work, share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hey Frank, I was able to get around the 401, now getting a more specific error which says missing registration. I had apparently missed the to: field thinking omitting it would mean it would be a broadcast to all.  So can you tell me where I can find the registration ID for the client ?

Comment: Thank you Frank ! I was finally able to fix it by making a successful POST message to the FCM server. I ended up posting to a topic in the form of "/topics/news" in the to: field. Also added the post data in JAVA using the right carriage returns and was able to get it working.